# How to restart a snap(craft) package which claims it has no service?

Tags: ubuntu

My specific case is mattermost-desktop, but this may help people having the same issue with other snaps.
Installation and running mattermost-desktop works fine, but when it comes to restarting or stopping it, snap refuses.

specifically, `sudo snap stop mattermost-desktop` or `sudo snap restart mattermost-desktop` results in `snap mattermost-desktop has no services`.

I tried a number of other snap commands, to no avail.

So, how does one stop or restart a snap like this one?

(OS is Ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: You close the contained program, then start it again. What’s the goal here? In the end, snaps are just sandboxed programs.

Comment: The goal is to update a snap where the normal way does not work. Yes, closed state.

Comment: Ah, now that’s a totally different problem, which you should be asking its own question about, including all the usual stuff (error messages/incorrect behavior, what you tried, what you researched, details about your system and so on).

Answer (score 1):

`sudo snap stop package_name`

example:  `sudo snap stop spotify`

Can use too...
`restart`, `start`

example:

```
snap find aws
snap install aws-cli
snap remove aws-cli
```

Fast search I found this...
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/managing-ubuntu-snaps/

Comment: That's how it works for normal "snaps"/packages which get listed with "snap list". I specifically asked about snaps which do not.